# Strange behavior of R function ecdf

Tags: r, distributions, descriptive-statistics

I have a very long vector, `x`, of integer values in the range [0, 1000]. I then use `stats::ecdf` to create 
empirical cummulative distribution function (ECDF). Since the minimum value of `x` is 0, I expect 
that `ecdf(x)(0)` would be equal to zero. However, this is not true

```
> length(x)
[1] 28694
> min(x)
[1] 0
> max(x)
[1] 1000
> summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    0.0   576.0   762.0   720.4   977.0  1000.0 
> summary(x[x<=576]) #summary of the first quantile
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    0.0   172.0   391.0   330.2   490.2   576.0 
> f <- ecdf(x)
> f(0) # I expect 0
[1] 0.0425176
> f(-0.00000001)
[1] 0
> f(762.0) #median 
[1] 0.5004879 #as expected
```

What may be the source of strange behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong.  Run...

```
mean(x==0)
```

... and you will see why.  (Side note:  `x == 0` creates a vector of logicals where TRUE has a value of 1 and FALSE has a value of 0.  The mean of this vector of logicals tells you what proportion of your dataset has a value of 0.)  This matches f(0).  Why?  Because, per the help file for that function:

> The e.c.d.f. (empirical cumulative distribution function) Fn is a step
>   function with jumps i/n at observation values, **where i is the number
>   of tied observations at that value**. Missing values are ignored.

(emphasis added).  Therefore, the ecdf at 0 matches the proportion of your vector x that has a value <= 0.

Comment: Yep, that explains it. I was sure that ecdf at 0 matched the fraction of x<0 and was also not expecting that **my** `x` would contain that much 0's. Thank you